# Is there any difference between primary and secondary OpenID?

Tags: discussion, openid, login

I just associated a second OpenID with my account, and I notice that I now have a "swap" option which will swap the new one to be my "primary" OpenID.  But is there any reason I would care which one is primary and which one is secondary?  I can still log in with either, as far as I can tell, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have two associated IDs, adding a new login replace the primary ID. If you wanted to replace your alternate ID instead, you'd need to:

1. swap the primary and alternate IDs.
2. use the "new login" feature to replace the primary (formerly secondary) ID.
3. (optionally) swap them again to restore the original primary ID.

#### See: [We Now Support Multiple OpenIDs](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/)

Comment: I'm still confused...  does it matter which openid is primary or secondary?

Comment: @kanamekun: not unless you're trying to change one.

Comment: hmm... that's weird, seems like it'd make more sense for the new open id to replace the secondary one.  you'd think "primary" would mean "more important" and you'd want the less important one to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any difference between the two when I've used them.  I believe that it is simply so that you can have a backup in case of a problem with one.